# How can I shift types inside a type list?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Using `std::tuple<>` as my type list, I would like to be able to have a template:

```
template<std::size_t i_src, std::size_t i_dst, class Tuple>
struct tuple_shift
{
    // implementation
};
```

A contained `type` alias would return the shifted type list so that the following example compiles:

```
// move type at i_src to i_dst and shift the types
// i_src = 1, i_dst = 3 : right to left shift

using tuple_t          = std::tuple<int, char, long, double, float>; // before
using expected_tuple_t = std::tuple<int, long, double, char, float>; // after

using result_tuple_t = tuple_shift<1, 3, tuple_t>::type; // actual result

static_assert( std::is_same<expected_tuple_t, result_tuple_t>::value, "!" );
```

Sample use case: stable sort of a type list.

---

Here's my solution, which is in another galaxy in terms of conciseness when compared to [TC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032871/2296177), but it avoids having to make comparisons for every index; it depends on template deduction to work.

This is actually a partial solution; the full solution is specialized to expand the sequence correctly when `i_src == i_dst` or `i_dst < i_src`. It works by generating the index sequences and then merging it all into one.

For `i_src = 1, i_dst = 3`, where the sequence is `<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>`, the following is generated (in pseudo-code):

```
left_index_seq    = <0>
shifted_index_seq = <2, 3>
right_index_seq   = <4>
```

Which is then expanded to:

```
sequence = <left_index_seq, shifted_index_seq, i_src, right_index_seq>
         = <<0>, <2, 3>, 1, <4>>
         = <0, 2, 3, 1, 4>
```

**Implementation**

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t offset, class IndexSequence>
struct index_sequence_offset;

template<std::size_t offset, std::size_t... Is>
struct index_sequence_offset<offset, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = std::index_sequence<( offset + Is )...>;
};

template<std::size_t offset, class IndexSequence>
using make_index_sequence_offset = typename index_sequence_offset
<
    offset, IndexSequence
>::type;

template<class IndexSequence>
struct index_sequence_size;

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct index_sequence_size<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...( Is )>
{};

template<std::size_t i_src, std::size_t i_dst, class Tuple>
struct tuple_shift_indices
{
private:
    template<class LIPack, class SIPack, class RIPack>
    struct tuple_shift_indices_impl;

    template<std::size_t... l_is, std::size_t... s_is, std::size_t... r_is>
    struct tuple_shift_indices_impl
    <
        std::index_sequence<l_is...>,
        std::index_sequence<s_is...>,
        std::index_sequence<r_is...>
    >
    {
        using type = std::index_sequence<l_is..., s_is..., i_src, r_is...>;
    };

public:
    using type = typename tuple_shift_indices_impl
    <
        std::make_index_sequence<i_src>,
        make_index_sequence_offset<i_src + 1, std::make_index_sequence<i_dst - i_src>>,
        make_index_sequence_offset<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1, std::make_index_sequence<i_dst - i_src - 1>>
    >::type;
};

template<std::size_t i_src, std::size_t i_dst, class Tuple>
struct tuple_shift
{
private:
    template<class IndexSequence>
    struct tuple_shift_impl;

    template<std::size_t... is>
    struct tuple_shift_impl<std::index_sequence<is...>>
    {
        using type = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<is, Tuple>...>;
    };

public:
    using type = typename tuple_shift_impl
    <
        typename tuple_shift_indices<i_src, i_dst, Tuple>::type
    >::type;
};
```

Comment: _"I already have a solution, but I would like to see how others tackle this problem. If anyone wants to see my solution, I'll post it as an answer."_ Nope! Please don't do that. Post what you have as answer along in 1st place plesee.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ On it, I'm modifying it to reduce noise.

Comment: _"but I would like to see how others solve this problem"_  This might fairly qualify your question better to go at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't want my code reviewed, I want to see how others solve this problem. Therefore, it is not for Code Review.

Comment: What's not if this isn't a request for Code Review?? You wan't to see others opinions upon your code, and what would be their ways to improve it, or choose different design decisions than you did. What are you actually bothering with my advice?

Comment: This approach asking questions here is completely silly. If you have an answer, post it along, period.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you have any other issue other than the fact that I already have a solution? If you don't, I don't see why you're making a big deal out of me wanting to see other people solve this problem.

Comment: Well, what's hindering you showing your solution in 1st place, such we can have a fair discussion, if it's good or not? I don't see your point holding back your (may be brilliant, and outstanding answer). So just post it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Solution has been added

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The reason I didn't post my solution initially was because I'm not using `std::integer_sequence<>`, so I had to change up quite a few things.

Comment: @user2296177 code review is not to review your code and give you a score. If you post it there, you are basically asking for improvements or a better way to do what you're doing. That is exactly what you are wanting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constexpr function to calculate the actual index mapping:

```
constexpr std::size_t old_index(std::size_t new_index, std::size_t src, std::size_t dst) {
    if(new_index == dst) return src;
    if(src < dst && new_index >= src && new_index < dst) return new_index + 1;
    if(src > dst && new_index <= src && new_index > dst) return new_index - 1;
    return new_index;
}
```

Then the implementation is trivial.

```
template<std::size_t i_src, std::size_t i_dst,
         class Tuple, class = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>>
struct tuple_shift;

template<std::size_t i_src, std::size_t i_dst,
         class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
struct tuple_shift<i_src, i_dst, Tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<old_index(Is, i_src, i_dst), Tuple>...>;
};
```